# The SQL Server Network Interface library could not deregister the Service Principal Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, spn

After windows patching (windows 2008 R2 , SQL Server 2012 Sp2). I could not start SQL Server Service . I get error 1067 and this from the error log* The SQL Server Network Interface library could not deregister the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x13, state: 2. Administrator should deregister this SPN manually to avoid client authentication errors."
Yes it is a production system and any help is welcome. I tried using domain account that has sysadmin and local admin privilege.

Thanks

Comment: One does not have anything to do with the other. The error regarding SPN has nothing to do with the service not starting. Error 1067 just means the service did not start, it is not sufficient information to determine why.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to same issue and I wander for about hours to fix it, finally I ended up repairing the existing database server 2016.

download SQL Server Installation setup package from this link:
[SQL Server 2016_x64_ENU](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2016/06/01/sql-server-2016-full-and-final-version-available-download-it-now/)
Go to setup.exe >> Maintenance >> Repair

While repairing, error prompted saying it could not restart the servers, yu can cancel that and let the repair finish. Once finished, start the SQL Servers

Right click on start and go to Computer Management >> Services and Applications >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services >> right click on all the servers and hit on start.

This fixed my issue and was back on track. I am still looking for a better answer on why or what can cause that but for now, here's the fix!

Good luck guys!

Answer (score 0):

Folks,
I was able to resolve the issue by repairing SQL Server installation in Add/Remove Program. I restarted the service in SQL Server Configuration management and SQL Server Service,SQL Agent started and the application is also up and running.
Hope this will help out someone.
Thanks